# Repairing postfix - unable to create /root/mailbox.lock

Tags: debian, postfix

Because of recent policy changes at our office's ISP (no more SSL or TLS 1.0, only TLS 1.1+), I've had to ditch ssmtp as our mail relay on a Debian 9 workstation. I reinstalled postfix, which automatically removed ssmtp. Great. But there were some problems with installation, probably due to apparmor: postfix just would not configure, and no amount of `apt-get clean`, `apt-get install -f`, or `dpkg -a --configure` would solve that. I disabled apparmor, reinstalled ssmtp, purged postfix, fixed dependencies, and then reinstalled postfix. Now postfix automatically went through its post-install configuration no problem. Great.

The problem now is that postfix is unable to create a lock file for messages from root. Here's the error message it produces in mail.warn when I try to send a test message as root:

```
Feb 25 10:30:56 Mephistopheles postfix/local[9195]: warning: unable to create lock file /root/mailbox.lock: Permission denied
```

I'm pretty sure on my other Debian workstations the default spool directory was /var/mail. So, first question, is the spool directory the problem, or the mailbox directory? And is it a question of group postfix having permissions on a directory? I don't want to give postfix RW permissions on /root.

I tried setting `postconf mail_spool_directory=/var/mail/` and `postconf home_mailbox=` (null), then running `postfix reload`. So far no dice.

Here's my /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs. 
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes 
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
#restricting use to TLS 1.1+
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv11
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL, LOW, EXP, MEDIUM, ADH, AECDH, MD5, DSS ECDSA, CAMELLIA128,
3DES, CAMELLIA256, RSA+AES, eNULL
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated
defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = Mephistopheles.[our domain].com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, [our domain].com,
Mephistopheles, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [our ISP name]:25 mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail/ 
home_mailbox =
```

On previous instances of postfix (on other machines) installation has been totally seamless. Not sure what about the ssmtp/postfix swap gummed this up, although apparmor clearly played a role.

Comment: This error looks like it is being generated by messages *to* root rather than *from* root.  From memory, `postfix/local` is used for message delivery to it's recipient.

Comment: It is of course possible that mail from rooot is failing and then the bounce email (back to root) is generating the error you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you redirected email addressed to root to your non privileged OS account?

http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#notify

> **/etc/aliases:**
>   postmaster: you
>   root: you

Comment: Yes, my /etc/aliases includes "postmaster: [my email address]" and "root: [my email address]"

Comment: Seems like you were right. My email address was specified in /etc/aliases, but it also included "/root/mailbox" for root mail. (Not sure how that got there, since this is a pretty fresh system, and I wouldn't have put it there.) Anyway, I removed the /root/mailbox, reloaded/restarted postfix....and got a different error. So mailbox lock is resolved.